# Images not being cached in Google

Tags: google, google-search, google-image-search, google-cache

I have a [banner printing site](http://www.bannerbuzz.com) and my site is on top position in Google, but I have one problem - the images (Banners) of my site are not cached in any search engine.

Comment: Cached? or Indexed? Can you give an example of an image thats not being handled by Google the way you want?

Comment: Hey thanks Mike for ans my que, my banners are not able to cached you can see attached url's images which are not cached in any search engine : http://www.bannerbuzz.com/custom-signs.html please check it and if you have some solution then please tell me thanks

Comment: Sorry - still not any clearer whether you mean "indexed" as in showing in Google Image Search (in which case @mvark's answer is correct) or "cached", as in crawled and kept a copy of when Google crawls your page like: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:fY26U3LV1HkJ:www.bannerbuzz.com/custom-signs.html

Comment: Thanks a lot... I can't see any of my images in google images, so if my pages are cached after that my images will able to index, so the problem is cached my images...

Comment: No, the problem is that Google isn't "indexing" your images. Follow the links in @mvark's answer below

Comment: Thanks mike i am getting so many information regarding some good points from this page, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Here are few tips to make Google index images on your site -

- [Use descriptive filenames](http://www.seomoz.org/ugc/using-google-image-search-to-drive-traffic-to-your-site) for your images
- [Always add the ALT attribute to your images](http://www.labnol.org/internet/using-alt-img-attributes-in-image-tags/5450/) (and include the
  TITLE attribute only if the image is a link)
- [Supply an image sitemap file](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=178636)
- [Provide good context for your image](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=114016)